# What comic/graphic novel software allows you to dynamically draw/change panel shape?

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, comics

Sorry if this is the wrong place -- I saw a software advertised a month or so ago that demoed a user re-drawing panel shapes in the software itself. It was a very easy way to dynamically create a variety of panels -- you just drew lines and the panels would snap to the closest approximate shape. Or you could cut a panel in half with just a single line drawn, etc.

Does anyone know what this software is called? I've been searching for a long time and I can't for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good graphic novel software:

- [Manga Studio](http://my.smithmicro.com/manga-studio-comic-illustration-software.html)
- [Clip Studio Paint](http://www.clipstudio.net/en)

I think Clip studio paint is the advertisement you saw

Comment: Ahhh yes, I believe it was Clip Studio Paint, after looking at some of the demos online. Thank you very much! I am downloading a trial version now.